Pytorch inference in parallel GPUs
I have a trained model and 4 GPUs. I have a dataset which I want to split in 4 (and process with the same batch size on each GPU) independently of each other and essentially add the results I get from each GPU. I'm new to parallel processing in general and my google searches of torch.multiprocessing etc were unhelpful.
A minimal example of my problem is as follows:
I've tried running the below script with both $python and $torchrun.
import torch 
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader
import torch.distributed as dist
import torch.multiprocessing as mp

net = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(1, 10), nn.Tanh(), nn.Linear(10,1), nn.Flatten(0)) # some model 

x = torch.linspace(0, 1, 100).unsqueeze(1) # the full dataset
s0 = net(x).sum() # some action of the model on the full data  
# I want to preform the same action on the data in parallel and get the same result


def run_inference(rank, world_size):
    # create default process group
    dist.init_process_group("gloo", rank=rank, world_size=world_size)
    net.to(rank)

    x = torch.linspace(0, 1, 100).unsqueeze(1) # re-define data here? (Based on google results)
    data = TensorDataset(x) 

    world_size = torch.cuda.device_count()
    batch_size = 10
    data_loader = DataLoader(data, batch_size=batch_size, drop_last=False, num_workers=world_size)

    sum_i = 0 
    for idx, data in enumerate(data_loader):
        sum_i += net(data[0]).sum() # how to store and add results from different GPUs?


world_size = torch.cuda.device_count() # 4 in my case 
mp.spawn(run_inference,
    args=(world_size,),
    nprocs=world_size,
    join=True)

